# How to add field select query as field in Magento Collection

Tags: magento

I have Magento collection called `mymodule/class`. I have two tables `class` and `student` in my Magento db.

Class table:

```
id     clas_name
```

Student table:

```
id   class_id    student_name
```

`class_id` in student table is foreign key of `id` in class table.

I want to make `mymodule/class` collection so that sql looks like below:

```
select a.*, (select count(id) FROM studetn 
                WHERE class_id = a.id) as student_count 
FROM class a
```

Or, I want to make `mymodule/class` from above sql.

how to do any suggestion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you have to add columns in your query. In scenario you already have collection, let us assume your $collection variable like:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("mymodule/class")->getCollection()
```

So, you have to modify query like:

```
$collection->getSelect()->columns(
        array(
            'student_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT count(id) FROM student WHERE class_id=main_table.id)'
        )));
```

Above expression will generate query as you wrote.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create module control file Module name as

```
 Amit_Custommodule.xml at app/etc/modules/
```

code of

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and

Path Of config.xml is app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/etc/

As we define codepool is community then it path app/code/community

Here Amit folder  is Namespace of module and  Custommodule is module name

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <custommodule>
                <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>custommodule_resource</resourceModel>
            </custommodule>
            <custommodule_resource>
                <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <custommodule>
                        <table>studetn</table>
                    </custommodule>
                </entities>
            </custommodule_resource>
        </models>

    </global>

   </config>
```

Model file Custommodule.php path is `app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/Model` and it code

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Custommodule extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custommodule/custommodule');
    }

}
```

If we define model then we need define resource class of model Custommodule.php

Resource class my module is Custommodule.php `app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/Model/Resource`/ and code

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Resource_Custommodule extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custommodule/custommodule', 'id');
    }
    public function getMyCount($std)
{
    $Table = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('custommodule/custommodule');

    $select = $this->getReadConnection()->select()
        ->from(
            array('main_table' => $Table),
            array(new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(main_table.id)'))
        )
        ->where('main_table.id = :id');

    $bind = array('id' => (int)$std->getId());
    $counts = $this->getReadConnection()->fetchOne($select, $bind);

    return intval($counts);
}

}
```

this two files makes final module `Mage::getModel("custommodule/custommodule")->load($primaryKeyOfTable);`

Now we need to class collection file of that module which is  fetch all data of the table

Collection file path is `Collection.php app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/Model/Resource/Custommodule` also its code

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Resource_Custommodule_Collection
extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract{
    protected function _constuct(){
        $this->_init('custommodule/custommodule');    
    }
}
```

also

```
$Collection=Mage::getModel("custommodule/custommodule")->Collection(); 

foreach($Collectio as $each)
{
$each->getMyCount();
}
```

More details 
http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/

Comment: Thanks Amit for great explanation. It is defiantly great article. But it is not answer I am looking.

Comment: @krishna code is work goods...Elisa yours question also good . I am give both of two upvote